# how to use array by included file in php?

Tags: php, arrays, include, return, require

I have a *init.php* file with the following code:

```
$engines = [
    "id" => [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C'
        ],
    "url" => [
        'D',
        'E',
        'F'
        ]
];
return $engines;
```

as you can see in this file there is only an array that need for initialize the site that is included in another file as follow:

```
    $engines = require "init.php"; //the file with the array
    $urlsite='';

    switch ($_POST['engn'])
    {   
        case $engines['id'][0]: 
            $urlsite=$engines['url'][0]."/download/"; 
            break;  
        case $engines['id'][1]:
            $urlsite=$engines['url'][1]."/fixes/";
            break;  
        case $engines['id'][2]: 
            $urlsite=$engines['url'][2]."/12555/";
            break;
        default:
            echo '{"err":"true","errtype":"1"}';
            break;
    }
```

The problem is that the *$engines* array seems to be null (or something similar) when called in the switch statement.

I also tried to remove the *return* command in the *init.php* and include it without assignment but, in this case the array don't exist at all (return me an exception error for nonexistent variable in the *switch* statement).
I can not understand what is wrong.

How do I use an array in another file?

Thank you very much.

edit: I use EasyPHP with php version 5.4.24

Comment: Have you var_dumped $engines after the include to check that it contains your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `$engines` to the value of the require statement. Simply dont do this and it should work fine. In other words, change:

```
$engines = require "init.php"; //the file with the array
```

to:

```
require "init.php"; //the file with the array
```

and remove the `return`statement from `init.php`.

This works because `require` simply includes the code from the external file in the current file ***before*** it is executed. While, in unusual circumstances, it can be used as you have attempted, in this case it does not need to run and return a value like a function. Since you have set a value for `$engines` in `init.php`, the array will be created by the code when it is run by your current file.

Comment: What OP is doing here is perfectly valid PHP, there's no need to change assignment on the require: although not commonly seen, an include file with a return in it can be used in this way

Comment: Thanks Mark - I've never seen `require` used like that but I have added some detail to the answer to include your point.

Answer (score 0):

init.php SB

```
<?php

$engines = [
    "id" => [
        'A',
        'B',
        'C'
        ],
    "url" => [
        'D',
        'E',
        'F'
        ]
];
?>
```

You dont need to use return there, then as cronoclee said...